# c# WinRT Updating ListView with DatePicker

Tags: c#, listview, datepicker, windows-runtime, .net-4.5

I am using Visual Studio 2013, .net 4.5.

I am having a problem with updating my ListView from my DatePicker. When changing a date it should update my ListView with the new dates via my DateChanged event handler, but it does not. I also have an update button on the application that filters the data in the ListView in a different way. When I change the ListView.ItemsSource in my button's event handler, the ListView data updates immediately. However, when I use the same code in my DatePicker's event handler, the ListView doesn't change.

Stranger still, if I change the date picker (the ListView doesn't change) and then click the update button it will update the ListView to reflect the date changes made in the date picker, as well as the filter changes associated with the Button.

Then after I've updated the ListView once via the button method, then every time I change the DatePicker, my date event handler is able to properly update the ListView.ItemsSource and the ListView changes its data.

```
 private void touchedUpdatePeriodRangeButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Code here calculates displayFromPaymentNumber and displayToPaymentNumber
    // ... snipped for clarity
    ItemListView.ItemsSource = this.schedule.amortizedPayments.GetRange(displayFromPaymentNumber - 1, displayToPaymentNumber - displayFromPaymentNumber + 1);
}

 private void changedDate(object sender, DatePickerValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DateTimeOffset date = e.NewDate;
    this.schedule.generateWithOriginationDate(date.DateTime);

    ItemListView.ItemsSource = this.schedule.amortizedPayments.GetRange(this.displayFromPaymentNumber - 1, this.displayToPaymentNumber - this.displayFromPaymentNumber);    
}
```

Comment: Could it have something to do with the different counts in `GetRange()`? In `touchedUpdatePeriodRangeButton()` you use `displayToPaymentNumber - displayFromPaymentNumber + 1` which makes sense, but in `changedDate()` you use `displayToPaymentNumber - displayFromPaymentNumber`...

Comment: It turned out that I hadn't initialized displayToPaymentNumber and displayFromPaymentNumber variables so the DatePicker event was failing due to the range in the list being invalid. The reason why it worked after the touchedUpdatePeriodRangeButton is because it updated the variables and was able to work appropriately. Thanks for your comment, because it made me go look at that bit of code which lead me to the solution.